# Anylogic - liquid color

Tags: anylogic

How to change the color of the liquid when two pipes merge to a given one, depending on which of the flows prevails?

The output is the color of the liquid, which is the first to reach the confluence point. Used Pipeline and Fluid Merge.

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wJJP.jpg)

When the speed changes in section 1, the color of the liquid should change in section 0. Speed up to 30 is one color, speed over 30 is another color.